# SQL "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" When Referencing Another Foreign Key

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a foreign key to a foreign key (which I think is possible) but I keep getting an error that the constraint is incorrectly formed

```
CREATE TABLE Staff (
    ssn INT, 
    name VARCHAR(127), 
    gender VARCHAR(127), 
    age TINYINT UNSIGNED, 
    address VARCHAR(255), 
    phone_number CHAR(12), 
    wage FLOAT(3,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn));
CREATE TABLE Admininstration (
    ssn INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Staff(ssn), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ssn));
CREATE TABLE Wards (
    ward_clerk INT,
    ward_id CHAR(2), 
    floor_number TINYINT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ward_clerk) REFERENCES Administration(ssn), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ward_id)
);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `HospitalManagement`.`Wards`
       (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

If I change the last statement to reference the Staff table

```
CREATE TABLE Wards (
    ward_clerk INT, 
    ward_id CHAR(2), 
    floor_number TINYINT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (ward_clerk) REFERENCES Staff(ssn), 
    PRIMARY KEY (ward_id)
);
```

it works but that's not what I want to do.  If this isn't possible I know how I'll change it but I'd like to do it this way.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: `Adminstration` is not the same as `Administration`. You misspelled your table name. I'm voting to close this question as a simple typographical error.

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I'm just a little tired, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: We've all made typos and similar mistakes! Sometimes it takes another pair of eyeballs to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Where appropriate, make columns `NOT NULL`.

Be aware of the serious security implications of storing SSNs.

`wage` is between -9.99 and 9.99?  Cheap.  Don't use `FLOAT` for money; use `DECIMAL`.

Comment: I've tried making ssn and and ward_clerk not null but I have the same issue, maybe you mean a different column?  This is just a school project so I won't be storing real SSNs.  I changed wage to DECIMAL(5,2), I thought 3 meant digits left of the decimal but I see now it means total.  Thank you for the help.